# How do you specify which postgres database to grant schema privileges using psql

Tags: postgresql, psql

I have a shell script that's called by docker to create a database and a user for an application as soon as the container is created. The database and user are created fine but the user is not granted privilege to schema *public* in the application db, so when the application runs, it throws an error `ERROR: permission denied for schema public`. Below is my script

```
#!/bin/bash

psql -U postgres -tc "SELECT 1 FROM pg_database WHERE datname = 'myapp_db'" \
| grep -q 1 || psql -U postgres -c "CREATE DATABASE myapp_db"

psql -U postgres -c "CREATE USER myapp_user WITH PASSWORD 'some_password'"
psql -U postgres -c "GRANT ALL ON DATABASE myapp_db TO myapp_user"
psql -U postgres -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO myapp_user"
```

What I look in pgadmin, I noticed that the *myapp_user* is granted privileges to schema *public* in the default database `postgres` but not in the intended `myapp_db` database. How do I modify the statement **"GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO myapp_user"** so psql applies it to **myapp_db**?

Comment: the whole script can only connect to one database. so you need connect to myapp_db and do the grant.

Comment: Hi @jian. How do you have psql connect to myapp_db to grant the schema privilege? That's the gist of my question. I'm new to psql so bear with me.

Comment: Did you check the manual about how to use psql and how to start a database connection?

Answer (score 0):

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-grant.html
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html

You command didn't explicitly mention the database name, but psql will have default value. if default value works then you are connect to the default database.
You can only connect to one database one psql command.
Hope the following simple one will work.

---

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/local/pgsql15/bin/psql -U postgres -p 5415 -d test15 -c "CREATE DATABASE myapp_db"
/usr/local/pgsql15/bin/psql -U postgres -p 5415 -d test15 -c "CREATE USER myapp_user"
/usr/local/pgsql15/bin/psql -U postgres -p 5415 -d test15 -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO myapp_user"
/usr/local/pgsql15/bin/psql -U postgres -p 5415 -d myapp_db -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SCHEMA public TO myapp_user;"
/usr/local/pgsql15/bin/psql -U postgres -p 5415 -d myapp_db -c "GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO myapp_user"
echo done
```